# Hook for changing excerpt content when excerpt not set

Tags: posts, filters, hooks, excerpt

Title says pretty much all of it. I need a filter that I can use to change excerpt content for those posts that have no excerpt set.

Now, I've tried both `the_excerpt` and `get_the_excerpt`, they both pass one parameter, and in both cases said parameter is empty string.

That said, I will need to hook onto a filter that has access to the auto-generated except, and lets me change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper hooks for modifying the post excerpt are the ones you already tried: [`get_the_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_excerpt/) and [`the_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_excerpt/), and WordPress actually uses the former one to generate an excerpt from the full post content, *if* there's no custom or manually-specified excerpt for the post — below is the relevant code in `wp-includes/default-filters.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt', 10, 2 );
```

So if you want to access the auto-generated excerpt, then with the `the_excerpt` hook, you can do it like so:

```php
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', function ( $excerpt ) {
    return has_excerpt() ?
        'Has custom excerpt: ' . $excerpt :
        'Automatic excerpt: ' . $excerpt;
} );
```

But take note, the automatic excerpt may not necessarily be the one initially generated by WordPress and WordPress might not even be the one that generated the excerpt — plugins could have completely overridden it or just customized it, just as you can do the same.

And as you may have guessed it, you can remove the default WordPress filter and then use your own callback to generate your own "automatic" excerpt:

```php
remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', function ( $excerpt, $post ) {
    return $post->post_excerpt ?
        'Has custom excerpt: ' . $excerpt :
        'Here, create your own excerpt.';
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Ie., it's not executed at all. Funny thing, `wp_trim_excerpt` nor `get_the_excerpt` are being called at all, from what I can see. Only `the_excerpt` gets called.

Comment: Hi Milos. Are you sure you put the code in the right file/place, e.g. the root of the theme `functions.php`? Have you done something with the `$excerpt`, e.g. `$excerpt .= ' testt';` ? Have you tried disabling plugins? Are you sure the post does *not* actually have a custom excerpt?

Comment: This was DiVi theme. It obviously overrode the original process for creating an excerpt.